# How can we make ls --color =always work in Sun Os

Tags: shell, colors, solaris, ls

Is there a way or hack in which we can make ls --color=always work on a Sun OS box.

Or is there any other way in which that can be achieved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Install **GNU ls(1)**, use it instead of the system ls(1), and then set up aliases the same as under any unix.  [This blog](http://blogs.oracle.com/tao/entry/colorful_terminal_in_solaris_11) recommends sunfreeware.com; you might also try [Blastwave](http://www.blastwave.org/).

EDIT: actually, see the first comment on that blog.  You can use the GNU ls(1) that's already provided, either by changing your PATH or, more cleanly, `alias ls="/usr/gnu/bin/ls --color=auto -AFC"` -- or, with your inferior options :-)